# Why 'MSG_EOF' is not found in my sctp program?

Tags: c, sctp

```
sctp_sendmsg(sock_fd, readbuf, rd_sz,
    (SA *)&cliaddr, len,   sri.sinfo_ppid,
    (sri.sinfo_flags| MSG_EOF), sri.sinfo_stream, 0, 0);
```

In ubuntu12.04, I compiled as this: `gcc -lsctp temp.c -o temp`. Howerver, gcc said that:

> error: ‘MSG_EOF’ undeclared (first use in this function)

What is wrong?

Comment: Umm... where are some newlines?

Comment: It has been renamed `SCTP_EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? 
Solaris 10 was the only OS that I know of to use the macro MSG_EOF. 
If you are using a newer version of Solaris, or if you are using Linux, then you should use SCTP_EOF.